# Hacking by sending PHP variable from another host

Tags: php, security, include, require

Is it possible to hack website by sending PHP variable from another host? For instance:

I have a file secure_content.php:

```
<?php
    if($fgmembersite->Login())  //placed at the top to avoid the warning: headers already sent
     {
     $login = TRUE;
     }  
   //intentionally removed {else $login === FALSE}

   // echo some  contents

    if ($login === TRUE) 
    {
    //echo secure data
    }

    else
    {
    echo "You are not authorised to view this content";
    }
?>
```

And an attacker have a file in his webserver named: hack.php

```
<?php
$login = TRUE;
require_once "http://mywebsite.com/secure_content.php";
?>
```

1. Is it possible the hacker to view the secure content?
2. How to avoid processing our scripts using include/require from other webserver?

Comment: No! unless you use `eval` function!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$login = TRUE;` instead of `$login === TRUE;` ?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to process your scripts from another webserver.
Your server will not give the entire PHP source code to the remote server, rather it will give *the output of running your script*.
No worries here.

You cannot avoid processing your scripts using include from other webserver, because that is not possible in the first place. So there is nothing to prevent.

Comment: What is remove server?

Comment: It's a typo, meant "remote".

Comment: what about my second question?

Answer (score 2):

As Denis said, though I want to add few interesting caveouts from personal experience administrating sites.

People often rename their php scripts into something like secure_content.php.back while editting the file - fear it. As then, the attacker can download your PHP script accessing (`secure_content.php.back`). Having source-code is not enough to hijack variables, but is already a vulnerability. It will get amplified, if your `secure_content.php.back` has some configuration variables like `$database_password`

Also, if you are to uninstall PHP from your web-server, Apache (or whatever) will serve your secure_content.php as a text file - is also a risk. Just keep in mind when you are to tinker with your PHP engine.

Comment: To prevent first case- Add this line in .htaccess :             AddType application/x-httpd-php .back

Answer (score 1):

No. Your server will run the script and then send the results to the evil server.

A similar thing to what you mention can occur in older versions of PHP if `register_globals` is on. This would allow someone to call `http://mywebsite.com/secure_content.php?login=true`.

This would cause `$login` to be set to true at the start of the script. Thankfully `register_globals` is now off by default and is deprecated in 5.3 and removed in 5.4. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php).

Comment: what about my second question?

Comment: If your server is setup correctly `.php` files will always be processed on your server. There isn't a difference between another server requesting  your page and a web browser. As it stands other servers can't process your PHP.